# Angular 1.5 component with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-model with a component? I would like to bind a scope variable to a component with ng-model. I have [plunkered my issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/72XTUweimR2fzXg35xet?p=preview). I would like the component my-input to be binded to the variable from the scope userData.name.

I am using Angular JS 1.5.6 components, and want to avoid using directive.

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>My form with component</h2>
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>First name</label>
        <my-input placeholder="Enter first name" ng-model="userData.name"></my-input>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've fixed the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Scp00IPSvhWNLBv3AFAE?p=preview) for you.

Names of you parameters have to correspond to the names in your component. You should be using camelCased names in your component and kebab-cased in your templates. Example:

```
  bindings: {
      myPlaceholder: '@',
      myModel:'='
    }

 <my-input my-placeholder="Enter first name" my-model="userData.firstName">
```

Regarding your question about using ng-model - you can use any parameter as far you define it in your component. In this case the name of your parameter should be **ngModel**.

Comment: it work very fine thanx a lot! I would have one last question. Please, how do you to bind data when you have a form component composed with button and input components : see this new [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/jLnrDeledkkJBLaKWKjZ)

Comment: Disclaimer: because this answer is not using ngModel, form validation won't work

Comment: MISLEADING ANSWER. What you're seeing here is not a usage of ngModel but rather a binding to an attribute with the same name. This makes validations not work, and is using a two-way binding which is not supposed to be used in components.

Comment: Many people just need things to work and don't care about doing things the right way and it's a perfectly valid opinion. All in all I downvoted the answer because I consider Stackoverflow a source of knowledge, not a "ill do your homework, just copy/paste". Sorry for the rage :)

Answer (score 39):

You can use this code:

```
function myInputController($scope) {
    var self = this;
    this.$onInit = () => {
        this.ngModel.$render = () => {
            self.model = self.ngModel.$viewValue;
        };
        $scope.$watch(function() { return self.model; }, function(value) {
            self.ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
        });
    };
}
module.component('myInput', {
    require: {
        ngModel: '^ngModel'
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="vm.model"/>',
    controller: myInputController,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
};
```

Comment: regarding this.ngModel being undefined did you try putting it inside the $onInit hook instead of the timeout?

Comment: @jzig yes, that's how I do it now. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think this is a better solution for the question since it actually uses ngModel. NgModel is necessary for some use cases such as form validation.

Comment: Don't use $watch here, use this.$onChanges see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component and https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks#onchanges for examples.

Comment: @ries isn't $onChanges triggered when binding get changed? this example don't have bindings.

Comment: This was helpful for me: http://luxiyalu.com/angular-requiring-ng-model-as-component/

Comment: @Saike This what I'm getting: `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'myInput', can't be found!`

Comment: @pilau try asking new question with source code provided and link to this question, with info that this one didn't work.

Comment: @pilau you need to set attribute to component's dom: data-ng-model="your.model"

Comment: @pilau like this: `<my-input data-ng-model="your.scope.model"></my-input>`

Comment: what about using setters and getters on the controller and get rid of self.model? `Object.defineProperty(this, 'model', {
    get: function() {
       return self.ngModel.$viewValue
    },
    set: function(model) {
        self.ngModel.$setViewValue(value)
    }
})`

Comment: @Gabriel, good idea on getters and setters, but should 100% only be used in typescript, so much prettier. `get model() {this.ngModel.$viewValue}` and `set model(value) { this.ngModel.$setViewValue(value) }`